# Run gitlab pipeline only for commits

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, merge-request

Currently gitlab runs a pipeline when creating a merge request + branch with the GUI.
Is it possible to skip this pipeline, since it's only repeats the last pipeline from the default branch?

We tried with:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

This works to skip new branch pipelines, but it doesn't run a pipeline for new commits on branches which have no merge request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stop pipeline execution when a new branch is created and in the same time run when a new commit happens on a branch

Try change from:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

To

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

The rule

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  when: never
```

Will stop the execution of a new pipeline when a new branch is created

The rule

```
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
```

This is added to allow a new pipeline trigger when a commit happens on branch,
because if the event is not a merge request the pipeline won't execute.